# LSTM for time series regression: Training and Validation loss start very low and don't improve much

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, regression

I'm training an LSTM model for a time series regression task. The data is minute by minute prices, which don't change very much. I took the log returns `np.log(timeseries[column]/timeseries[column].shift(1))` as input and created rolling windows. The values for these log returns range from -0.1 to 0.1, so they are very small to begin with. When I train the model, the training and validation losses start off very small and hardly change epoch to epoch.

Here are the losses using mae loss on the first few epochs (using a batch size of 256 here for speed in trying different things, but the same thing happens with smaller batch sizes too):

```
Train on 653173 samples, validate on 653173 samples
Epoch 1/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 142s 218us/step - loss: 0.0014 - val_loss: 0.0013

Epoch 2/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 138s 211us/step - loss: 0.0013 - val_loss: 0.0013

Epoch 3/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 139s 213us/step - loss: 0.0013 - val_loss: 0.0013

Epoch 4/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 141s 215us/step - loss: 0.0013 - val_loss: 0.0013

Epoch 5/50
653056/653173 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0013
```

Here are the losses using mse loss:

```
Train on 653173 samples, validate on 72566 samples
Epoch 1/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 130s 199us/step - loss: 4.4182e-06 - val_loss: 2.3261e-06

Epoch 2/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 129s 197us/step - loss: 4.2763e-06 - val_loss: 2.2734e-06

Epoch 3/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 131s 200us/step - loss: 4.2189e-06 - val_loss: 2.1721e-06

Epoch 4/50
653173/653173 [==============================] - 129s 197us/step - loss: 4.1975e-06 - val_loss: 2.1675e-06

Epoch 5/50
458752/653173 [====================>.........] - ETA: 37s - loss: 4.1741e-06
```

And here is the model itself:

```
def LSTM_model_2(LSTM_units=[200,200], n_steps_in=10, num_features=6, loss='mse', LSTM_activation='relu', verbose=False):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(LSTM_units[0], activation=LSTM_activation, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, num_features)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(LSTM(LSTM_units[1], activation=LSTM_activation))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(num_features))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
  opt_LSTM = Adam(lr=0.001)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt_LSTM, loss=loss)
  if verbose: 
    print(model.summary())
  return model
```

The goal of the project is to minimise a custom error function: `np.mean(np.absolute(np.log(y_pred/y_true)))`
As you can imagine, this error on values very close together is quite low. When I use a baseline of the previous minute's price as the prediction for the current minute's price, the error comes out to 0.00108
None of my models do much better than that, the lowest I have gotten is 0.00104
I imagine it has to do with the model not learning based on the losses above.
Any ideas why this is happening or what to do to fix it?